# change "-" symbol between site name and description in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

This might have been asked a number of times before but I'm struggling to find a nice clean way to change the "**-**" symbol between Page Title and Site Description on all pages, where I'd like it to just say Site Name and Tagline, to clarify...

Is there any easy way to change from

**Homepage Site Name - Site Tagline**
TO
**Homepage Site Name | Site Tagline**

[image]

Comment: add filter using wp_title

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you researched your question?

[How to change the seperator in the title.](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/203279/how-to-change-the-seperator-in-the-title)

Or you can install plugin to do it.

Example with Yoast SEO.

[image]

Comment: Thanks buddy... I did some research before & made some changes, Just got some empty results

Answer (score 0):

go to wp-admin panel => Settings => General and change Site Title.

OR

go to wp-content\themes\your_theem\header.php change whatever you want.

change in title tag.

Comment: But I want to change the symbol between Sitename & Tagline.. Do you know any solution for that? .... Default is set to **-** i would like to change that to **|**    .Thanks for answering..